# spirng-boot how to add interceptor in custom spring-boot-start

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

how to add an `interceptor` like `FilterRegistrationBean` in third spring-boot-start use autoConfiguration?
Or is there other tricks to use the interceptor

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register this Interceptor with InterceptorRegistry by using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter as shown below −

```
@Component
public class ApplicationInterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   LoggerInterceptor loggerInterceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(loggerInterceptor);
   }
}
```